# Call another java program when an android app makes a request

Tags: java, android, twitter

In my android project, whenever a user asks to see a specific #hashtag, i want to check if any tweet had changed in twitter database about this hashtag and update my database according to that changes. The problem here is, i need to run another java project in my server to get updates from twitter and change my database. But, i don't know how to call another java program when a request made from an android app.

I don't know where to start or which path i should follow. I would be appreciated if anyone show me some way.Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi hello_stackoverflow,

visit this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api and have a look at the twitter webservice api, especially this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets, this would provide you with the search option the API provides you. With this you can search for a custom query within tweets on twitter.

So you'll not need to call an external java application, just call the RESTful Webserive from twitter and send a query with user input hashtag.

Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick,thank you so much for answering. The reason that i am calling another java program in the server side is to calculate something according to this new updates and add this solutions into database too.I don't want to do all this calculations in my android app. So even if i update my db without this external java program, i'll need to call it to do some calculations.Is there any way to call a java program which is at the server side when my app sends a request or should i call this program like in every 10 minutes instead of app request? Thanks again.

Comment: Your Android App only takes inputs from users and shows the received results to them, have i got that correctly ? In that case i would provide a webservice on your serverside application and call this from your android app, let the server do all the calculate work and only parse JSON or XML (how you like) in the android app.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So it is possible to reach my java classes in the server side and get data with web services? Sorry for confirmation,I don't know too much about web services

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaEE6/7 Development?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not

Comment: Contact me on my e-mail (in my SO Profile), i'll create an example and share it with you.

Comment: Hi @Patrick, i can't see your mail address in your profile but i saw this example that you shared [Create a RESTful WebService and serve it by Glassfish 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361980/create-a-restful-webservice-and-serve-it-by-glassfish-4/20361981#20361981) . Is this what were you talking about?

Comment: Yes, this is what i was talking about. Within this ItemsService Class you could call your other Java Class and let do it all the work. Write at fhvr@streaken.de